# prove $A = \cup\mathcal{P} (A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove:

if A is a set then $$A = \cup\mathcal{P} (A) $$

but I don't know how to reach from $x \in A$ to $x\in\cup\mathcal{P} (A)$.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $\{x\} \in \mathcal P(A)$

Comment: It can help to remember what $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is.  It is literally the set of all subsets of $A$, including all of the singleton sets as well as $A$ itself.

Comment: Hint: $A\in\mathcal P(A).$

Comment: Technically this problem is worded incorrectly. It should be instead to show the equation $A=\cup_{B \in \mathcal{P}(A)} B$.

Comment: @Mike Given a family of sets $\mathcal{F}$ it is common notation to define $\bigcup \mathcal{F} = \{x~:~\exists F\in\mathcal{F}~(x\in F)\}$.  The problem is phrased just fine, you just gave another alternate notation for the same thing the OP did.

Answer (score 0):

To proof the assumption, we have to proof that

$$ a \in A \iff a \in \cup \mathcal{P}(A) $$

Notice, that $ a \in \cup \mathcal{P}(A) \iff \exists S \in \mathcal{P}(A), a \in S$.

Let us first proof $ a \in A \implies a \in \cup \mathcal{P}(A) $. If $A$ is nonempty, let be $x \in A$. Then there is a singleton-subset $ \{x\} \subseteq A $. By definition this subset is in $\mathcal{P}(A)$, which completes this part of the proof. If $A = \{\}$, $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{\{\}\}$ and $\cup \mathcal{P}(A) = \{\}$.

To proof that $ a \in A \impliedby a \in \cup \mathcal{P}(A) $ assume for contradiction, that there is an element $x \in \cup \mathcal{P}(A)$, but $x \notin A$. Then there would be a set $\{x\} \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. By definition of the powerset, $\{x\}$ would be a subset of $A$ which in turn would imply that $x \in A$. This leads to a contradiction as required, so we know that all elements of $\cup \mathcal{P}(A)$ are in $A$.

$\blacksquare$